# Why angular event emitter doesn't work when component is nested inside other component?

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter, ng-content

In card component html I have ng-content and I put card-item component inside the card component.
Why in this case I can`t emit value ?.

Example 1.

```
card.component.html

  <div>
      <ng-content>
  </div>
```

---

```
    <card>
       <card-item (closeEmitter)="onClose($event)">
       </card-item>
    </card>
```

If I move car-item component outside of card component  the event emitter works fine.

Example 2.

```
card-item.component.html

<div>
  <div class="card-header"> header </div>
  <div class="card-body"> content </div>
  <div class="card-footer"> footer</div>  
</div>
```

---

```
<card></card>
<card-item (closeEmitter)="onClose($event)"></card-item>
```

Is there any way to emit value as in the first example?

Answer (score 0):

you should call the event emitter on an html element or ng-container.

```
<ng-container (closeEmitter)="onClose($event)">
<card-item></card-item>
</ng-container>. or on an html element 
<div (closeEmitter)="onClose($event)">
<card-item></card-item>
</div>
```

Comment: or you can create a class of hidden and show or use ngHide or ngShow with a variable - ngClass is the cleanest because you can use css visibility: hidden and set the height to 0 on hide class.

Comment: Is it possible to call event emitter on div or  ng-container ? I don't think so.

Comment: yes - but the better way is to use ngClass and a boolean operator to set the class [ngClass]="yourtruthyvariable ? 'show':'hide'"

or some variance - its much cleaner, one can listen for the event from the component.

Comment: @Nikolay we don't know what could be invoking the event emmitter - or if he has some sort of host binding on the component side.  i was making the assumption that he did - and that this was a smaller portion of a larger piece of code - maybe i'm wrong - it happens.